# mongoose update inside array object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How to update mongodb based
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNYgL.png)

need to update in_state Object  based on `testid` and `user_id`

code

```
 const test = await usertest.update( 
      { "testid" :"oOEbG3ycsl5ZIPrFNk172SVma0zTwD6xHvpUM4JWKAj9fg18nRCtq1B0XLdYeuiQh","user_id":"63297394d10aa70d52708a4c"},
      {
       $set: {
       
          'testdata.1.in_state': in_state
       } 
      }
     
     )
```

how can achieve this

Comment: i dont get what you mean your code sample should work

Comment: update query based on condition

Comment: could you give the specific condition I seem to not understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try referencing the `testdata` elements with `$`:

```
const test = await usertest.update(
  {
    testid: 'oOEbG3ycsl5ZIPrFNk172SVma0zTwD6xHvpUM4JWKAj9fg18nRCtq1B0XLdYeuiQh',
    user_id: '63297394d10aa70d52708a4c',
  },
  {
    $set: {
      'testdata.$.in_state': in_state,
    },
  }
);
```

Comment: `testdata.$.in_state': in_state,`   $ refers Index number ? 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGkc9.png

Comment: @todaysprint I didn't understand your question, can you elaborate?